# Application of identity theorem for a power series only convergent on |R^+

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let $g : \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

$0 = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}_0} \frac{g(i)}{i!} \lambda^i$ for $\lambda > 0$.

A professor of mine said,  that $g(i) = 0$ follows from the identity theorem for power series. However, in the theorem it is clearly stated that the power series has to be convergent in some neighbourhood of the center point of the series. In this case, the center point appears to be $0$, so the conditions for the identity theorem are not met. I have tried using a different center point on the negative half lines, but i keep ending up with negative values for $\lambda$ for any neighborhood of a center point.

I.e. $\lambda := z - a>0$ for some $a<0$, then $0 = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}_0} \frac{g(i)}{i!} (z-a)^i$ and the power series is supposed to be convergent for any $z \in B(a,\varepsilon)$, but $a-\varepsilon < z < a$ yields $\lambda < 0$...

Comment: You know that for all $\lambda > 0$ the sequence $\lambda^ii!^{-1}g(i)$ is bounded, so the power series has an infinite radius of convergence, thus you can apply the identity theorem.

Comment: Sorry, what result is this?

Comment: I knew it as Abel’s lemma, but I suppose it’s not canonical. It is, nonetheless, the first fundamental result in the theory of power series. You check the wikipedia page out though: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(i)\neq0$ for some $i\in\mathbb N_0$, let $j$ be the smallest element of $\mathbb N_0$ such that $g(j)\neq0$. Then\begin{align}0&=\frac0{\lambda^j}\\&=\frac{g(j)}{j!}+\frac{g(j+1)}{(j+1)!}\lambda+\cdots\\&=\frac{g(j)}{j!}\left(1+\frac{g(j+1)}{g(j)(j+1)}\lambda+\frac{g(j+2)}{g(j)(j+1)(j+2)}\lambda^2+\cdots\right)\end{align}when $\lambda\neq0$. But this is impossible, since$$\lim_{\lambda\to0}\frac{g(j)}{j!}\left(1+\frac{g(j+1)}{g(j)(j+1)}\lambda+\frac{g(j+2)}{g(j)(j+1)(j+2)}\lambda^2+\cdots\right)=\frac{g(j)}{j!}\neq0.$$

Comment: While this proof is very nice, and I really want to mark it as accepted, unfortunately, it does not use the identity theorem for power series

Comment: What about his? Since the power series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{g(i)}{i!}\lambda^i$ converges for every $\lambda>0$, its radius of convergence is $\infty$; in other words, it converges for every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. But then the function $\lambda\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{g(i)}{i!}\lambda^i$ and the null function are equal on $(0,\infty)$ and therefore, by the identity theorem, are equal in $\mathbb R$. So, $(\forall\lambda\in\mathbb R):\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{g(i)}{i!}\lambda^i=0$ and therefore $(\forall i\in\mathbb N_0):g(i)=0$.

Comment: Nice! I did not know of this symmetry argument for the radius of power series. How exactly do I know that the series converges for $\lambda < 0$, too? I'll gladly accept your pretty proof.

Comment: It is a standard theorem about power series that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ cnverges for some real number $x$, then it converges absolutely for every number $y$ such that $\lvert y\rvert<\lvert x\rvert$; it is a consequence of the ratio test. In particular, if a power series converges for every postivie real number, then it converges for any real number.